# How to remove a certain html snippet from a string

Tags: ios, swift, string

In a String, I store the raw contents of an HTML file. In this file is the following:

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
        <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="page" title="Page" accesskey="f" id="searchInput" class="search" autocomplete="off" readonly="">
</div>
```

I want to remove this, along with this:

```
<div><a title="Open main menu" href="/wiki/Special:MobileMenu" class="mw-ui-icon mw-ui-icon-element mw-ui-icon-mainmenu main-menu-button" id="mw-mf-main-menu-button">Open main menu</a></div>
```

Is there a simple operation to do this? Or would tokenizing the whole file work better?

Comment: I have used this library in the past for parsing html on swift, https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HTML parser library as suggested by Sri, which I would suggest if you're going to further manipulate the HTML or if you can't guarantee the HTML won't change in the future. Although if you're only striping out the specific HTML then you could use a regular expression as a lighter alternative.

```
do 
{
    let html = "<html> ... </html>"
    let regex:NSRegularExpression  = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<div\\s*(?:class=\"input-wrapper\")?>\\s*(?:<input type=\"search\" name=\"search\" placeholder=\"page\" title=\"Page\" accesskey=\"f\" id=\"searchInput\" class=\"search\" autocomplete=\"off\" readonly=\"\">)?(?:<a title=\"Open main menu\" href=\"\\/wiki\\/Special:MobileMenu\" class=\"mw\\-ui\\-icon mw\\-ui\\-icon\\-element mw\\-ui\\-icon\\-mainmenu main\\-menu\\-button\" id=\"mw\\-mf\\-main\\-menu\\-button\">Open main menu<\\/a>)?\\s*<\\/div>", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, html.characters.count)
    let htmlStripped:String = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: html, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range:range , withTemplate: "")
} 
catch 
{
        // ...
}
```

Not fully tested, Swift 3.0.

Comment: Just noticed that will also remove empty div's, may want to adjust that.